# How to limit rsync to a single file tranfer?

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm using linux rsync to transfer large amounts of data to an off-site machine. The files transferred are backup volumes 5G or 10G in size. The actual process works the other way around, it is the off-site machine that runs a script calling rsync to a list of remote machines in an infinite loop.

Conceptually (it is much more complex in reality) :

```
while () do
   for remote_host in (host list) do
       rsync -a remote_host:srcDir local:destDir
```

This works well, but when a very large full backup runs (once a month), there is a large number of files that change on a particular remote target and the rsync command for that machine prevents the other machines from being sync'ed for days.

What I would like to do is sync only one file from each machine in each rsync call. Since the call to rsync is made in an infinite loop, all files from all remote machines will eventually get transfered, but "equally". At some point all machines will be in sync except for the one with the largest amount to be transfered, which will be the only one transferring a file in each loop until either it's whole data has been transferred, or one of the other machines have new files to sync.

Comment: **IF** I understand you correctly all you need to do is to generate a list that matches hosts and files up against each other, and then iterate over *THAT* instead, extracting both the host and the file name and feed these into the `rsync`?

Comment: @tink the remote host list is immutable so it is hard-coded in the script. What I need is a way to get a single file at a time to be sync'ed from each host. The remote hosts have no idea what the off-site machine is currently syncing so it can't generate a single-item list - that determination has to be done by the off-site machine.

Comment: I'm confused "the remote host is immutable" vs. "from each host" .... how does that work?

Comment: @tink I know the list of hosts to connect to and that doesn't change

Comment: `rsync` of 10G incremental will need to traverse the list of files on BOTH machines to develop the list of new or changed files to update when run with the `-u` option. This will take several minutes over gigabyte ethernet. Over wireless, or a limited WAN connection, this will be painfully much slower. While if there are no-changes, `rsync` can use a checksum to quickly determine no transfer is needed, if you individually transfer new files and then run a sync, I don't believe the checksum will be present and all files will need to be scanned again to create it.

Comment: The rsync program was designed to copy the minimal set of changes for a collection of files. If you don't need that, don't use rsync. To copy a single file always, use `scp`.